# Avro schema versioning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

Sorry this is a beginner AVRO question.

My Java microservice takes a payload request which has a schema version element, there can be a number of different versions of that payload each with a slightly different format.  Is it possible to do a lookup against the AVRO schema registry using that version number then use that schema to validate the received payload.

Is this a valid and possible AVRO use case?

The intention then is to process this data in the Java microservice some more before sending on-wards.

Maybe AVRO is not the correct technology, but please advise if otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lookup against the AVRO schema registry using that version number

The Avro schema ID in the registry is an incrementing number, not something which your data is really indexable by.

I think what you're looking for is just a version ID, which the Confluent Avro Schema Registry supports by

```
GET /subjects/:name/versions/:id
```

Comment: I have one related follow on question.  I am not using AVRO here in conjunction with Kafka, I am using it for JSON object type validation.  Is this ok to do, thanks?

Comment: You can use JSON or Avro or any other data format within the topic, AFAIK. It's just easier to preserve backwards compatible messages while using the Confluent Avro serializers

Comment: What I am asking is that I am NOT using Kafka here.  I am asking about just using the AVRO schema to verify a local POJO then pass that data on somewhere else.  Is this possible?  Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: You tagged your question with Kafka, though... And the only "Schema Registry" that I know of requires a Kafka installation.

Comment: In any case, you can use the Avro Maven Plugin to create a POJO from an Avro schema. I don't really understand what "verification" you are doing, but you probably can use any data format to compare against anything else. Not really sure why you think Avro needs to be used